# How to create snap YAML file of program written in golang sciter library?

Tags: snap, golang

could you please help me? How to create YAML file for golang application written in language go named golang and sciter library https://sciter.com/ ? I mean how what to write to yaml file to have working snap for snapcraft? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
package main

import(  
"log"  
"github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter"  
"github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter/window"  
)  

func main() {  
w, err :=window.New(sciter.SW_TITLEBAR|sciter.SW_RESIZEABLE|sciter.SW_CONTROLS|sciter.SW_MAIN|sciter.SW_ENABLE_DEBUG, nil)  
if err != nil {  
log.Fatal(err)  
}  
//log.Printf("handle: %v", w.Handle)  
w.LoadFile("simple.html")  
w.SetTitle("Example")  
w.Show()  
w.Run()  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing too special with Sciter other than the requirement that libsciter-gtk.so to be installed (copied) in the same folder as resulting go executable.

So you will have basic Go rules: https://docs.snapcraft.io/go-applications/7818
and libsciter-gtk.so (x64) listed in fileset : https://docs.snapcraft.io/snapcraft-filesets/8973